# Append to INCLUDE environment variable from Visual Studio 2013 Command Prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I want to append a value to my INCLUDE environment variable. This should be easy.

For example typing

```
set PATH = "C:/new_entry;%PATH%
```

works, and can be verified by

> echo %PATH%

But doing the same with INCLUDE does not change anything!

Furthermore, INCLUDE is not listed as an environment variable in System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables, so Visual Studio command prompt is picking it up from somewhere else.

I looked at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\varsvall.bat, but it is not helpful

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" goto x86
if not "%2" == "" goto usage

if /i %1 == x86       goto x86
if /i %1 == amd64     goto amd64
if /i %1 == x64       goto amd64
if /i %1 == arm       goto arm
if /i %1 == x86_arm   goto x86_arm
if /i %1 == x86_amd64 goto x86_amd64
if /i %1 == amd64_x86 goto amd64_x86
if /i %1 == amd64_arm goto amd64_arm
goto usage

:x86
if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion

:amd64
if not exist "%~dp0bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion

:arm
if not exist "%~dp0bin\arm\vcvarsarm.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\arm\vcvarsarm.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion

:x86_amd64
if not exist "%~dp0bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion

:x86_arm
if not exist "%~dp0bin\x86_arm\vcvarsx86_arm.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\x86_arm\vcvarsx86_arm.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion

:amd64_x86
if not exist "%~dp0bin\amd64_x86\vcvarsamd64_x86.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\amd64_x86\vcvarsamd64_x86.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion

:amd64_arm
if not exist "%~dp0bin\amd64_arm\vcvarsamd64_arm.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\amd64_arm\vcvarsamd64_arm.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion

:SetVisualStudioVersion
set VisualStudioVersion=12.0
goto :eof

:usage
echo Error in script usage. The correct usage is:
echo     %0 [option]
echo where [option] is: x86 ^| amd64 ^| arm ^| x86_amd64 ^| x86_arm ^| amd64_x86 ^| amd64_arm
echo:
echo For example:
echo     %0 x86_amd64
goto :eof

:missing
echo The specified configuration type is missing.  The tools for the
echo configuration might not be installed.
goto :eof
```

Comment: What is the output of the following command: `echo %INCLUDE%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Not Tested with VS 2013

But for older versions: The INCLUDE variable **can** be defined in machine Environment Variables, but is not required.  If it does not exist, then you can create it and define the value as you wish.

[image]

Also note that INCLUDE is defined/modified in the sub vcvar*.bat files called within the vcvarsall.bat script.

Comment: Setting the INCLUDE environment variable produces no change in Visual Studio 2017.  If create it and define an include path with it, Visual Studio still can't find the header.