# Global include path on Windows on VS2013

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, include, googletest

I should add a global include path to my system (i.e. it's Google Test so I need to include "C:\gtest\include")
I appended it to the PATH environment variable and restarted VS2013. However, VS2013 still complains about the missing .h files.

What's wrong with this IDE?!?

Comment: Do you mean the environment variable PATH?

Comment: yes, I corrected the question

Comment: Why don't you add it to the include directories in VS?

Comment: because the project is supposed to build as it is, I've already checked.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260758/append-to-include-environment-variable-from-visual-studio-2013-command-prompt) question?

Comment: yes but I don't know how to deal with it. I've correctly added C:\gtest\include to the PATH env. variable, it shows up on the prompt.

Comment: In that question they are talking about INCLUDE rather than PATH.

Comment: I've already tried to add the INCLUDE env. variable to both system and user scope. no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you definitely don't want the PATH environment variable.  You do want the INCLUDE environment variable.

Second, use a statement like `SET INCLUDE=C:\gtest\include;%INCLUDE%` to set it.

Third, that's only going to work in a command window that you're running command line builds in.

Fourth, so try setting it on your machine using This PC's properties "Advanced System Settings" Environment Variables dialog.  Remember to restart your VS2013 after setting it so it picks up the new env vars.

Fifth, why not do a `SET` (with no arguments) after you've set your non-working INCLUDE variable and paste the result into your question so we can all see what your environment variables look like - then we might be able to help you better.

Sixth, it's going to end up being your misunderstanding of how things work.  That's clear since you think the PATH env var has something to do with VC++ searching for include files.  So why the gratuitous "What's wrong with this IDE?!?" slam?  It's not winning you any friends.

Seventh, see the MSDN article [Setting the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx) for tips.  It came right up when I googled for "visual studio include environment variable", and it has help for you.